example scenario onchange using Intro.js at Vue
any example scenario reference for using function onbeforechange and onafterchange? The scenario is to open the popup when it reached to Step 2. I referred to this How do I fire a modal for the next step in my introjs? reference, but it did not work for me. If there's a best practice on how to response popup once the button next is triggered to step 2.
